# How can I fix the error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Tags: python, file, collections

I want to read the text given but it keeps giving me an error that I cannot understand. The function reads in a list (list) of string (str) called
decodedmap that contains the decoded map and returns the coordinate of the treasure as a tuple
(tuple). Y

```
def find_treasure(decodedmap):
with open(decodedmap, 'r+') as f:
    lines=f.read().split('\n')
    new_lines=lines[0:-6]
    new_lines_len=len(new_lines)
    list_new_lines=[]
    coor=[]
    res=()
    for new_line in new_lines:
        if new_line=='W: WATER                                    ':
            break
        l=list(new_line)
        list_new_lines.append(l)
    for i in range(new_lines_len):
        for k in range(len(list_new_lines[0])):
            if list_new_lines[i][k]=='T':
                coor.append((i,k))
    for tuple_x in coor:
        m=tuple_x[0]
        n=tuple_x[1]
        if m<=new_lines_len-2 and 1<=n and n<=len(list_new_lines[0]):
            if (m+1,n) in coor and (m-1,n) in coor:
                if (m,n-1) in coor and (m,n+1) in coor:
                    res=(m,n)
                    break
return res
```

Comment: include a sample of how your decodedmap looks like.

Comment: check the datatype of `decodedmap`  Seems like it is a list.